# Get course name where students are more than 100

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, database-design

I am learning to design a Database. I have found the following example:

You are asked to design a relational database for a college’s course registration system.

The system has the following requirements:

- A course can only be assigned one teacher
- A teacher can teach many courses
- A student can take many courses
- A course can have many students

My design would be this for this:

- ***Course***: *CourseID* (**Primary Key**), *CourseName*, *Hours*
- ***Student***: *StudentID* (**Primary Key**), *Name*
- ***Teacher***:  *TeacherID* (**Primary Key**), *Name*
- ***CourseTime***: *SectionNo* (**Primary Key**), *CourseID* (**Primary Key**), *TeacherID*, *Schedule*
- ***Enrollment***: *CourseID* (**Primary Key**), *SectionNo* (**Primary Key**), *StudentID* (**Primary Key**)

Now I am trying to get the course name where there are more than 100 students. How would I write query for this? Can any one please suggest?

i have tried the following :

Select c.courseName FROM course c Where (select count(*) FROM Enrollment e where e.courseID=c.courseID and ) but struck there.

Comment: Since this a homework problem, I'm obligated to ask-`What have you tried so far?`

Comment: there'll be joins, group by and having count  here

Comment: @DhruvJoshi I am trying to do this in this way: Select c.courseName FROM course c  Where (select count(*) 
                    FROM Enrollment e where  e.courseID=c.courseID and )
but i am not sure after this how should i select the students with moren than 100

Comment: @StackAcc please edit your question and add the above query in it. This will prevent downvotes from peeps!

Comment: Show some queries that return relevant parts. Read & act on [ask] & hits googling 'stackexchange homework'.

Comment: For many:many mapping tables, follow the tips here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

Comment: Tag properly!!!  SQL Server <> MySQL.  Which one are you using?????

Answer (score 0):

```
 select a.CourseID,CourseName from 
    enrollment a
inner join Course b
on a.CourseID=b.CourseID
    group by a.CourseID,CourseName
    having count(StudentID)>100
```

Comment: there is no coursename column in enrollment? @FatemehSheikhha

Comment: based on design in the question there is no coursename in Enrollment

Answer (score 0):

I am answering to help you out so that you can learn up on SQL and find SO generally a nice place. And well it's holiday time. Cheers!

So you need more than 100 students.  Now the only table where you find it is `Enrollment`

and you need coursename, so of course `Course` table is involved.

Now you must ask yourself, if they can be joined. 
Well certainly there's `CourseID` in both.
But what about `SectionNo`?
Well, umm, since a course can have only one teacher teaching it, and `CourseTime` has sectionNo with CourseID, and only defines what teacher and what hours. So that's likely redundant. But you must verify that.

In such case, we have our join criteria, and we just need to know if we can find courses which have > 100 students

100 students. So this is aggregation problem, so `GROUP BY` .

But group by by what? Well we need CourseName, and it's unique for CourseID so group by CourseName.

Now when checking aggregates with conditions, we use-- yes `HAVING`

So we have `HAVING Count(1)>100`

Full query below. Hope it helped and may you grow up to help others on SO.

```
  select 
    C.CourseName 
    from 
    Course C INNER JOIN 
    Enrollment E 
    on C.CourseID=E.CourseID
    group by C.CourseName
    having count(1)>100
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you had not considered the class section.  For example, English-101 is offered on Mon/Wed/Fri 8-10am, but also Tue/Thu from 6-9pm.. Both are 6 hours per week, but different sections.  Your Tue/Thu class could be 30 students, but the Mon/Wed/Fri is 100+...

Is this the type of scenario you are considering, look first at getting this 100 count basis first...

```
select
      e.CourseID,
      e.SectionID,
      count(*) 
   from
      Enrollment e
   group by
      e.CourseID,
      e.SectionID
   having
      count(*) > 100
```

So, this will give the per course + section anything that has more than 100 students.  Now, to get the course and all other information, join THIS results to those tables...  Something like.

```
select
      C.CourseName,
      C.Hours,
      CT.Schedule,
      T.Name,
      PQ.EnrollCount
   from
      ( select
              e.CourseID,
              e.SectionID,
              count(*) EnrollCount
           from
              Enrollment e
           group by
              e.CourseID,
              e.SectionID
           having
              count(*) > 100 ) PQ
      JOIN Course C
         on PQ.CourseID = C.CourseID
      JOIN CourseTime CT
         on PQ.CourseID = CT.CourseID
        AND PQ.SectionID = CT.SectionID
         JOIN Teacher T
            on CT.TeacherID = T.TeacherID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.CourseID,a.CourseName from 
    enrollment a
inner join Course b
on a.CourseID=b.CourseID
    group by a.CourseID,CourseName
    having count(*)>100
```

-- small modified version of Fatemeh